# Which trigonometric function I should use to generate the temperature with two peaks (i.e.one strong and one moderate peak)?

Tags: modeling, function, trigonometry

I want to generate seasonal temperature of Bay of Bengal. I want to do this with a trigonometric function. Seasonal temperature of Bay of Bengal has two peaks. One major peak during April and another moderate peak in November. Which trigonometric function I should use to do this?

[image]

Comment: Customary procedure is feed terms in pairs, each pair being one sine and one cosine term. I'd guess that you'd three pairs at least to catch that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be a bit fancy, you could run a DFFT (Discrete Fast Fourier Transformation) over your data , which would give you the approximate coefficients for a sum of sines and cosines -

$$f(t) = \sum{a_ncos(w_nt)+ b_nsin(w_nt)}$$

Then you could pick the highest coefficients and only use them, that would give you something similar to your original function, represented in terms of sin and cos.